# tmux: line-wise text selction in vi copy mode

Tags: tmux

In `tmux`, I generally want to select whole lines for copying.

How can I select text line wise, like `vi`'s `V` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tmux` command is `select-line`.

Here is a nice set of mappings I use (use `copy-mode` if not using `copy-mode-vi`):

```
# Selection / copy / paste
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v   send -X begin-selection  # default is <space>
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi V   send -X select-line
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-v send -X rectangle-toggle  # default is C-v, or R in copy-mode (non-vi)
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y   send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -selection clipboard -in'
bind p paste-buffer  # default ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution, in copy mode

```
1. move to the line you want to select
2. pres 0, then the cursor will move to the fist position of this line, 
same as vim
3. enter whitespace (start copy)
4. type $. Then it will highlight the whole line.
```